# Semidefiniteness of symmetric matrix checking main minors?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I know that for a given symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A}$ the matrix is positive definite / negative definite $\Longleftrightarrow$ main minors of $\mathbf{A}$ / $-\mathbf{A}$ are positive.

> Is it also true that for the case where all main minors are positive
>   or zero, that I can conclude the semi definiteness? I could only find
>   statements for the case in which all minors are positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, one cannot show semidefiniteness in that way. Consider the case where all main minors are zero. Does that mean that $A$ is positive semidefinite? Or is it $-A$?

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

is indefinite and has all main minors zero.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I allready thought that this would not work, but I couldn’t come up with a counterexample.